# What is the standard way to construct a polynomial in NTL?

Tags: c++, ntl

Specifically, I am trying to construct an polynomial in Z_p[x] modulo another polynomial P, which requires the usage of `ZZ_pE`. From the NTL library, the constructors for `ZZ_pE` are

```
ZZ_pE(); // initial value 0
ZZ_pE(const ZZ_pE& a); // copy constructor
explicit ZZ_pE(const ZZ_p& a); // promotion
explicit ZZ_pE(long a); // promotion
ZZ_pE& operator=(const ZZ_pE& a); // assignment
ZZ_pE& operator=(const ZZ_p& a); // assignment
ZZ_pE& operator=(long a); // assignment
```

As you can see, you can only construct a `ZZ_pE` from a number (`ZZ_p` or `long`) or from another `ZZ_pE`. Therefore the only polynomials that I have been able to construct are of degree 0. The following code sets moduli p = 100001 and P = x^4 - 1, and constructs a `ZZ_pE` g = 5.

```
// Declare polynomial and coefficient moduli
ZZ_p::init(ZZ(100001));
ZZ_pX cyclo = ZZ_pX(INIT_MONO, 4) - 1;
ZZ_pE::init(cyclo);

// Construct g
ZZ_pE g = ZZ_pE(5);
```

My goal is to make `g` a higher degree polynomial of my choosing. How do I do this?

A follow up question is: what is the standard (most efficient) way of initializing a polynomial (for example, in `ZZX`)? If I wanted to construct f = x^2 - 3x + 4, this is my current method:

```
ZZ list[3] ={ZZ(4), ZZ(-3), ZZ(1)};
ZZX f;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    f += ZZX(INIT_MONO, i, list[i]);
```

i.e., by adding each term of the polynomial separately in a for loop. It seems that the NTL library could benefit from a constructor like `ZZX([4 -3 1])`. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

For `ZZX` the official way is to set each coefficient on its own. 
For this there is the function

```
void SetCoeff(ZZX& x, long i, const ZZ& a)
```

See http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/ZZX.cpp.html for more details.

I'm not sure if this also works for `ZZ_pX`.